# Titlepage package shows \author as "presented by" - how to change that to "author"?

Tags: pdftex, titles, overleaf

if I use the following code to create a titlepage for example. The author given as \author{} is shown in the compiled PDF under the headline "presented by". How can I change that to "author" ?

```
\usepackage[TU-DD]{titlepage}
\university{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{image.jpeg} \\ \\ University }
\faculty{\LARGE Department }
\chair{\LARGE Chair }
\professor{\Large  Prof. }
\title{
  \Huge Determinants 
  \\[10pt]
}
\subject{Approach\large}
\author{\\[-10pt] \\ author \\[3pt]}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome! Please do not post snippets: complete your code with the `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` etc. so that we can copy and paste and compile it away. Help us to help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the `titlepage` package has been updated and is currently called `uni-titlepage`, see https://ctan.org/pkg/uni-titlepage. In this package you can change the author label by redefining `\presentedbyname`. This might also work in the old version, if not then updating would be a good solution.

Note that the redefinition needs to be done after `\begin{document}` because otherwise it will be overwritten by the package again.

MWE below. Note that I removed some errors related to ending empty lines (things like `\\ \\`) which is not allowed.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[TU-DD]{uni-titlepage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\university{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}\\University }
\faculty{\LARGE Department }
\chair{\LARGE Chair }
\professor{\Large  Prof. }
\title{
  \Huge Determinants 
}
\subject{Approach\large}
\author{George}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\presentedbyname}{Author:}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Following the discussion in the comments, the above code is a bit of a shortcut, bypassing the official interface. In KOMA-Script (which is used by `uni-titlepage`, both KOMA-Script and `uni-titlepage` have the same maintainer, Markus Kohm) the idea is to either **define** the string for the default language `english`, or specify a language for the whole document and then **redefine** the string that is provided by `uni-titlepage` for that language. The first version is as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[TU-DD]{uni-titlepage}
\newcaptionname{english}{\presentedbyname}{Authored by:}
```

And the second:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   
\usepackage[TU-DD]{uni-titlepage}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\presentedbyname}{Geschrieben von:}
```

Note the difference between `\newcaptionname` in the first version and `\renewcaptionname` in the second, which must be changed if you decide to add or remove the language setting at some point. Also for both versions the language must be correctly specified as an argument of the commands, `english` for the first version and the language corresponding to the `babel` setting in the second version. The shortcut approach above does not have these requirements, it will always work regardless of language settings. Of course it also doesn't *respect* language settings, but given that the goal is to overwrite the provided string with a custom alternative it is probably not required to generalize across languages.

Comment: @cabohah I agree in principle but since no language was specified in the question I wasn't sure that would work - and if it is a custom string anyway then making it language dependent doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @cabohah I added the official way (and some discussion) to the answer.

Comment: @cabohah I edited the answer to clarify that `uni-titlepage` is also part of KOMA-Script (the description in the log file is "KOMA presents the title page project") and therefore the package uses the KOMA interfaces.

Comment: @cabohah edited again - I guess you can say it is part of the wider KOMA(-Script) "ecosystem" though, even if it is not strictly part of the KOMA-script bundle itself.